# Referencing php on Dropbox in HTML

Tags: php, html, dropbox

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on a dilemma for me!! I am trying to use a PHP contact form on a website I am building but my hosting company does not allow me to upload my own PHP so I am trying to refernce the PHP in the HTML for the form.

What I thought, was that I could upload the php to my dropbox public folder so when the form was submitted, it would read in the php from dropbox and sent it on it's merry way. Everytime I click on the Submit button, the page just opens up the php in dropbox and doesn't submit the form.

The form itself looks fine; the top line of the HTML reads:

```
< form name="contactusform" method="post" action="link to dropbox" >
```

....rest of html......

Any ideas on how I can get around this??

Thanks

Comment: Find a better hosting provider.

Answer (score 4):

PHP requires a web server that supports PHP and is configured to parse the given file for PHP directives.

Dropbox does not do that for shared files.

Get some real hosting if you want to run PHP programs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a better host. Even a free host such as 000webhost would allow you to upload and execute PHP files without many limits.